# How to Bind ViewModel Object to View

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Good Day Everyone, I have this code

`Name.cs` (Model) - My Model

```
namespace CRUD.Model
{
    class Name
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`LocalViewModel.cs` (ViewModel) - My `ViewModel` - where I populate `name` upon loading.

```
using CRUD.Model;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace CRUD.ViewModel
{
    class LocalViewModel 
    {
        public Name name = new Name();
        
        public LocalViewModel()
        {
            name.FirstName = "Ambie James";
            name.MiddleName = "Moyano";
            name.LastName = "Nicolas";
        }
    }
}
```

`LocalView.cs` - (View Code Behind) where I bind to my `ViewModel`

```
using CRUD.Model;
using CRUD.ViewModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace CRUD
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class LocalView : ContentPage
    {
        public LocalView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new LocalViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

`LocalView.xaml` (View) - where I bind the object `name` to the controls

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="CRUD.LocalView">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Frame BackgroundColor="#2196F3" Padding="12" CornerRadius="0">
                <Label Text="Local Database" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="36"/>
            </Frame>
            <Label Text="First Name"  />
            <Entry Text="{Binding name.FirstName}"/>
            <Label Text="Middle Name"  />
            <Entry Text="{Binding name.MiddleName}"/>
            <Label Text="Last Name"  />
            <Entry Text="{Binding name.LastName}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

my problem is, it works fine but it always return blank or null value. even though it populate the `name` object right.

[image: result here]

does my binding `name.FirstName`, `name.MiddleName`, `name.LastName` in the `LocalView.xaml` right?

Comment: you can only bind to **public properties**.  `name` is a field, not a property

Comment: thanks for the idea Jason, do you mean i need to create a property for FirstName, MiddleName and LastName individually? ex.  "public string FirstName {get; set;}" and then bind it to my View? i tried "public Name name {get; set;}" then use the binding above but it does not work, it yells me an error.

Comment: Am I supposed to guess what "an error" is?

Comment: you also need to be sure your `Name` class is **public**

Comment: To sum up, a model issue, not a binding issue: 1. `public class Name {... `. 2. `public Name name {get; set;} = new Name();`